# Displaying and editing various item types in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I am displaying two types of items in ListView:

```
abstract class Item
{
    string ID { get; }
}

class ItemTypeA : Item
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}

class ItemTypeB : Item
{
    string ValueOne { get; set; }
    string ValueTwo { get; set; }
}
```

(of course, there's little more to them, they use various interfaces, but for the sake of example, I left that out, and showed just "final" structure of those types)

So basically in the ListView, there's always an ID column and the other columns depends on the item type.

I was thinking about using some sort of *dynamic columns* in `GridView` of `ListView.View`, where underlying view model will determine, which columns (or *attributes* of given item type) should be displayed.

Same goes for editing - there should be just one `TextBox` for **ItemTypeA** and two for **ItemTypeB** in the *edit area*.

So basically, my question is, how to solve this, while trying to avoid making complete separate views (with ListView and edit area) for each item type.

Also, I want to avoid editing items directly in ListView, since the item values can occasionally contain large amount of text (even multiple lines of text), and that would be hard to edit for user.

(I'm using Caliburn.Micro, but that shouldn't be too relevant to the problem).

Comment: You may set the second column's [CellTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector.aspx) to an appropriate [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). Similarly, you could use a ContentPresenter with an appropriately set [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contenttemplateselector.aspx) for the edit area.

Comment: But I do not want to display `ItemTypeB` in ListView as compound value of ValueOne and ValueTwo. I want two additional columns (ValueOne and ValueTwo), when ItemTypeB items are displayed in ListView and just one additional column (Value), when ItemTypeA items are displayed.

Comment: just direction... i think your VM should contain property for max column count in original list, and list property that for each original item return ienumerable, with items corresponding number of properties

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own DataTemplateSelector for ListViewItem:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTempolateSelector
{
     public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
     {
        // here select temaplate, from dictionary for example, using item.GetType()
     }
}
```

Your Item view model class:

```
abstract class Item
{
    string ID { get; }

    MyTemplateSelector TemplateSelector { get; }
}
```

Your ListViewItem style: